# jquery compress error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

http://pastebin.com/WfsVZ4nU

i got the following error when i compressed my javascript code.

Comment: http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/623/aa36891f30f04a67b51a079.png

Comment: and http://pastebin.com/EFJx0mGd

Comment: Please provide relevant parts of your source code in your question. Add additions to your question to your question by editing it, not by posting comments. And the first mentioned code is your source code? It's full of issues, according to http://www.jslint.com/

Answer (score 2):

When code is minified it is important not to miss any semicolon. Please check your code [here](http://www.jslint.com/) and put semicolon, where is needed (Lines 194 and 199).

Answer (score 0):

Missing semi-colons on (at least) lines 194 and 199.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), it is a series of checks that parse your Javascript and look for potential problems.

At the beginning, it is painful to use as many errors appear.
But then, it becomes a very useful safety net, to write solid JS that compress well.

And usually it can be easily integrated in your IDE so you forget it.
eg: It can check the JS each times you save the file.